# Group e-mails quickly, yet leaving them in the inbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I normally leave all my e-mails in my inbox, as I feel the overhead of creating a folder structure is not worth it, and often actually makes finding e-mails even harder. But sometimes I'd like to group e-mails quickly, e.g. if there are multiple threads concerned with the same short-term event.

Is there a way in Outlook 2010 to do so without moving them out of their respective original folders (i.e. Inbox, Sent Items)? Moving them into folders means I'll no longer see them when looking in the inbox, so I have to remember which e-mails I moved somewhere else.

Creating a tag for every such event is rather cumbersome as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is where [Outlook Search Folders](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-Search-Folder-961e78c8-9be5-48b5-b8b1-2c7beebe5b25) can be handy. If you have some kind of criteria for grouping mentioned emails, you can create a search folder and have all related messages in a single *virtual* folder (you can delete this folder safely later).

**Update**

To be able to manually group messages using search folder, you can use Outlook user-defined properties:

1. Open *Inbox* and switch to *View* ribbon tab.
2. In *Current View* group click *View Settings* button and then *Columns...* button.
3. Click *New Column...* button and type some name. For example: **Group**.
4. Click *OK*, *OK* and *OK* to save view changes.

Now you have the user-defined property named **Group** and you can use this property to create a search folder:

1. Create a custom search folder, say **Test**.
2. Open its *Criteria* properties and follow the *Advanced* tab.
3. Click *Field* button and select *User-defined fields in Inbox* -> *Group* in the menu.
4. Now you can either select *is not empty* Condition or specify *contains* *Condition* and *Test* as a *Value* if you want to strict search criteria to "Test" values only.
5. Click *OK* and *OK* to save search folder properties.

Now you have the search folder that will show you items with **Group** property set. How can we set this property with ease? By using VBA macro like this:

```vb
Sub SetGroupProperty()
    For Each Item In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        Item.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/Group", "Test"
        Item.Save
    Next
End Sub
```

This macro sets **Group** property value to **Test** for currently selected items. You can place the button that runs this macro right on your Outlook ribbon and then set this property for selected items with a click of a mouse. And these items immediately appear in our search folder!

Comment: Unfortunately, it is often difficult to find common criteria for grouping the e-mails automatically (and avoiding false positives). What I need is a mechanism to quickly allow me to manually select which e-mails would go in such a "search folder".

Comment: Updated the answer by adding "manual mode" =)